# How to click on that security hyperlink powershell

Tags: html, internet-explorer, powershell

I am trying to click on the "continue" hyperlink on that "there is a problem with this website's security certificate" website. the problem is that I keep getting the "you cannot call a method on a null valued expression" business. I am using powershell 2 with internet explorer. At this point I am not even trying to click on the element, just trying to get the computer to identify it as anything other than a null. I have looked at the other similar questions here and could not get any method to work. Below are the syntaxes that I have tried. What am I doing wrong? (at the very bottom I have reporduced the source for the element.

```
    $ie.Document.getElementsbyID("overridelink").click()
 $link= $ie.Document.getElementsbyTagName("A")| #Where-Object {$_.innerText -like "*Continue to this website*"} 
    $link.click()

    $ie.Document.getElementsbyTagName("A")| #Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq "Continue to this website"}

    $ie.Document.getElementsbyTagName("A")
    $ie.Document.getElementsbyTagName("a")
    $ie.Document.getElementsbyTagName()
    $ie.Document.getElementsbyTagName(*)
```

************************Page Source********
    
        
         
        
            
                Continue to this website (not recommended).

---

```
The code I have written  before I try to click the link
    $url = "https:// *the website goes in here/"
    $ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application 
    $ie.visible = $true 
    $ie.silent = $true 
    $ie.Navigate( $url )
    while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getElementById instead of getElementsById? This works for me :

```
$ie.Document.getElementByID("overridelink").Click()
```

Comment: I tried it. I still get the null valued expression error.